# Windows Phone 8 web browser history

Tags: url, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, browser, visited

Is there a way to get web browser history from Windows Phone 8?

I would like to save history of visited web sites from default web browser. In Android there is a content provider responsible for storing bookmarks and visited web sites. I haven't found the similar solution in Windows Phone. Is it possible or there is no such API for getting those logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API to access this on Windows Phone. You can always request new APIs using wpdev.uservoice.com.

Comment: Thanks. I just added new request to Windows Phone developer's feedback. Hope they will check that and give such ability in next releases.